# How to click an element on the page without loading it with capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

Is it possible to click on the element without loading the page using
capybara and Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. You need to load the page for the browser to know what to do when the element is clicked.

If the element being clicked just triggers a web request and you know what that web request is then you could just make that request using any of the ruby networking libraries but then you may run into issues with referrer, cookies, etc.